# Update/merge row data from the same table with common column name

Tags: mysql

I tried-->

```
UPDATE tbl AS r
INNER JOIN tbl AS f ON r.columnA = f.columnA 
SET r.columnB = f.columnB, r.columnC = f.columnC
WHERE f.columnA = r.columnA
```

tbl as table name

before

| ID | columnA | columnB | columnC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | data1 |
| 2 | 1 | data2 |  |
| 3 | 2 |  | data3 |
| 4 | 2 | data4 |  |

after

| ID | columnA | columnB | columnC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | data2 | data1 |
| 4 | 2 | data4 | data3 |

Comment: What if in columnB there is `data1` and `data2` for where `columnA =1` ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to know the unique indexes.

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick reply! columnB  has a data but not relevant or null ex; '---' or 'aaa' the same with columnC where the blank cell is null or irrelevant. this happened because it come from different sensors from arduino.  Thank you.

Comment: @RickJames How to SHOW CREATE TABLE?  thank you. I suppose the unique indexes is only the ID column.

Comment: Is `after` what you got?  Or what you want?

Comment: Do you want the results in `tbl`, including deleting rows 1 and 3?

Comment: @RickJames yes! thank you.

Comment: @SpawnRivera you need to clear what `irrelevant` values mean? If by irrelevant data there is  a value `yyyy` and the value which you want to retrieve is `data1` the max() function as explained in the answer below will get `yyyy`. Is there a pattern for the valid values ?

Comment: Yes, all blank row is defined by '-----' or 'xxxxx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and `MAX` are what you are looking for.  But you will need to rebuild the table.

First, verify that this give you what you desire:

```
    SELECT  MAX(id) AS id,
            columnA,
            MAX(columnB) AS columnB,
            MAX(columnC) AS columnC
        FROM tbl AS r
        GROUP BY columnA;
```

The to the rest of the steps to replace `tbl` with that result:

```
CREATE TABLE newt LIKE tbl;
INSERT INTO newt
        (id, columnA, columnB, columnC)
    SELECT  MAX(id) AS id,
            columnA,
            MAX(columnB) AS columnB,
            MAX(columnC) AS columnC
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY columnA;
RENAME TABLE TABLE tbl TO oldt,
                   newt TO tbl;
DROP TABLE oldt;
```

(The `SELECT` part it identical.)

`MAX` will pick a value in preference to `NULL`.

Comment: I got an error. ---> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO newt SELECT MAX(id) AS id

Comment: I really like what you did. but somehow I cannot make it work. hope for you understanding.

Comment: The SELECT part, I understand but the INSERT INTO, Igot an error is there a way to update its data using UPDATE tbl? Thank you

Comment: After the SELECT part, can we use the INSERT INTO without using CREATE newt? @Rick James. Thank you

Comment: @SpawnRivera if you have a lot of writings and the engine used is innodb consider using a single transaction such as described in [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/XzQpy1oz) . I have changed max with min. As per your questions above, you can't use update in this case, because the main table needs to be cleared . It seems that you are using a programing language. Have you the possibilities to execute the queries from a cli/ client software ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha the client side is a part of which only time is GET to the server which I assign to an ID which I chose. hench: columnA is editable.

Comment: @SpawnRivera - Using mysqli (or most other app interfaces), you must issue statements one at a time.  What I wrote can be pasted directly into the mysql commandline tool, but must be turned into multiple mysqli requests.

Comment: However, it is safer to issue the commands one at a time -- what if I have a mistake?

Comment: `CREATE .. LIKE ...; INSERT ... SELECT ... ` grabs the indexes.  `CREATE ... SELECT ...`doesn't.  (Since I can't see what indexes there are, I can't provide the latter.)

Comment: I was sloppy in one place:  `INSERT INTO x SELECT ...` assumes that the `SELECT` delivers exactly the right columns in the right order.  I'm changing my example to come closer to 'perfect'.

Comment: Ernest gives some more variants of how to combine CREATE or INSERT with SELECT.  Yes `TRUNCATE clears the table, but I preferred to "replace" the table with the 3-step process:  create new + rename + drop.  I like this because you can check what you have after each step.  If something goes wrong, you can still recover (until the final DROP).

Comment: @ErgestBasha - MAX vs MIN -- isn't there some issue with what happens with NULL?

Comment: @RickJames i used min in the example because the op mentioned that the irelevant  values are `----` or `xxxx` or `null` . Max will select xxxx instead of the needed values. Anyway this is for the op to decide.